# Copy all the files of a particular date using ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am having multiple file dumps in a single day
For ex
pqr_20220627_1.csv
pqr_20220627_2.csv
pqr_20220627_3.csv
abc_20220628_1.csv
abc_20220628_2.csv
abc_20220628_3.csv
xyz_20220629_1.csv
xyz_20220629_2.csv
xyz_20220629_3.csv

I have to fetch the files for the given date using the ADF in a different blob storage.
For example if for 2022/06/29 i only want
xyz_20220629_1.csv
xyz_20220629_2.csv
xyz_20220629_3.csv
these three files in my target blob.

Comment: Hi @Gaurav, can you please include the information about the source of these files (Blob storage or Data Lake gen2) and destination you want to copy it to.

Comment: Hey @SaideepArikontham-MT its a blob storage to blob storage transfer.

Answer (score 0):

To copy files that match a particular date to a target location, you can use `WildCard file path` with dynamic content. Consider the following demonstration.

- The following is the list of files in my source blob.

[image]

- Create a `copy data` activity in the pipeline of azure data factory. Create a parameter called `ip_date` where you can give the date using which you want to copy files. You can enter this value before triggering the pipeline.

[image]

- Now create the dataset using Linked Service to your source blob storage. Here, choose `Wildcard File Path` as the file path type. Enter the value for file name as:

```
@{concat('*',formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.ip_date,'yyyyMMdd'),'*.txt')}
```

- You can use `*.csv` instead of `*.txt`. Using this dynamic content you will get the wildcard file path as `*20220629*.txt` when `ip_date` has the value `2022/06/29` (* indicates 0 or more characters).

[image]

- You can now create the linked service for your sink if required. Publish and select `Add Trigger -> Trigger Now`. Before triggering the pipeline, it will ask you to enter the value for the parameter `ip_date`. Here you can enter date as `2022/06/29`.

[image]

- **NOTE:** The date value you give to `ip_date` should be of the format `yyyy-MM-dd` or `yyyy/MM/dd` or it will give you an error when you run the pipeline.
- The pipeline will successfully copy only the required files for the date `2022/06/29`.

[image]